# Crear gráfico con datos procedentes de multiples hojas de un archivo xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, matplotlib

Tengo un archivo de Excel con 7 hojas, cada hoja tiene dos columnas correspondientes a las variables x, y respectivamente, la cantidad de filas que tiene cada hoja varía desde los 11 registros hasta los 1500.

Quiero graficar los datos de las 7 hojas del archivo en **una sola gráfica** a fin de lograr una visualización de la distribución de los datos para posteriormente realizar una predicción con otros archivos del mismo estilo. Tengo:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_excel('../Datos MED/PAC1.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=0)

for hoja in data:
 print(data[hoja].head())
```

[Out]

```
COLX      COLY
0  0.29220  0.48056
1  0.38912  0.57264
2  0.42860  0.57324
3  0.46434  0.57534
4  0.51412  0.60434
COLX     COLY
0  1.01840  1.0269
1  1.47830  1.2806
2  0.98231  1.0265
3  1.45910  1.2307
4  1.73330  1.5503
COLX     COLY
0  3.6866  3.4092
1  1.9101  1.9670
2  3.0608  3.1680
3  3.9353  3.5477
4  3.2936  3.2536
COLX     COLY
0  2.2383  2.0533
1  2.2208  2.2791
2  3.1208  2.5423
3  3.3204  2.9278
4  2.8298  2.6610
COLX     COLY
0  1.8527  1.6261
1  1.3149  1.2348
2  1.5440  1.4508
3  1.7164  1.5310
4  2.1002  2.0323
COLX     COLY
0  0.95297  1.0690
1  1.06530  1.0663
2  0.92909  1.0524
3  1.10500  1.1047
4  1.24280  1.2844
COLX      COLY
0  0.87057  0.91529
1  0.91567  1.01200
2  1.10190  1.03980
3  1.26150  1.17440
4  1.24040  1.02680
```

Seguido de:

```
import seaborn as sns
#allow plots to appear within the notebook
%matplotlib inline

for hoja in data:
sns.pairplot(data[hoja], x_vars=['COLX'], y_vars='COLY', height=7, aspect=0.7, kind='reg')
```

Quise meter en un cliclo la graficación integrada pero no encuentro información de cómo hacerlo, lo que me regresa ese código es una serie de 7 gráficas, y lo que busco es algo como ésto:
[image: Gráfica buscada]

[Acá el código en Github hasta donde me alcanza](https://github.com/nanantza/Graficacion-multi-hoja-Excel-Python/blob/master/06_linear_regression_Excel(Pandas).ipynb)

Gracias de antemano por cualquier respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seaborn.pairplot` no permite indicar un eje en el que realizar el gráfico de forma directa, en su lugar usa el argumento `hue` para indicar una columna del DataFrame para diferenciar entre cada conjunto de datos.

La opción más simple es concatenar los *dataframes* en uno solo con [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) previamente. Con ayuda del argumento `keys` podemos crear una columna que indique la hoja de procedencia de la fila, columna que podemos usar para el argumento de `seaborn.pairplot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline


data = pd.read_excel('../Datos MED/PAC1.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=0)
df = pd.concat(data.values(), keys=data.keys(), names=["Sheet"])
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

sns.pairplot(df, x_vars='COLX', y_vars='COLY', hue="Sheet",
             height=7, aspect=0.7, kind='reg')
```

Lo que nos crea algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente, me funcionó a la perfección. Estuve considerando integrar las columnas en una sola hoja y hacer un mapeo emparejando columnas, sin embargo esta solución es mucho más eficiente ¡Mil gracias!